# Finder going crazy on opening a particular folder

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I have tested this on 2 macbook pros 2015 and 2016, Sierra and High Sierra respectively, it contains 4 html and javascript files, that my professor gave me and 1 of which i edited, i downloaded an image for my background and then the problem started occurring. By crazy i mean dirty animations and gui distorted and muddled up with the desktop, and non responsive, restarting and safe mode didn't solve it, however force quitting finder and never opening that folder again does. here is the folder: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3tty8p9avq3g61/dom.zip?dl=0

Comment: Not gonna touch that folder with a barge-pole :/

Answer (score 0):

If you've customized how the Finder should display a folder's contents, such as setting a particular list view or sort order, or setting a custom background color or picture for that folder, that information is stored in a hidden file called `.DS_Store`. I could imagine a malformed `.DS_Store` causing this problem. Try using the Terminal to delete the `.DS_Store` file:

```
rm dom/.DS_Store
```

I just carefully inspected that `.zip` file without decompressing it. There's definitely a `.DS_Store` file in there, as well as Finder metadata or resource forks for all the files, in AppleDouble format (inside a `__MACOSX/` folder). The AppleDouble format may just be an artifact of storing Mac files via a `.zip` file, and may not appear on the original filesystem where this `dom/` folder was stored, especially if that filesystem was a Mac native filesystem such as HFS+ or APFS. If this folder was originally created on a Mac native filesystem, that Finder metadata (or those resource forks, if that's what they are) would have been stored natively in the filesystem without needing a `__MACOSX` folder. I don't think it's common to see custom Finder metadata or resource forks for `.html` files, so there's a possibility that the Finder metadata may have something to do with it. If removing the .DS_Store doesn't solve the problem, you might want to remove that metadata (or resource forks if that's what it is; but I think it's far more likely to be Finder metadata than resource forks).